# Is there a way to output contents of a StyledDocument in HTML?

Tags: java

I need to save contents of StyledDocument, formatted with standard styles (e.g. bold, italic, various font sizes). And so there is my question - is it possible to output it into HTML someway?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer. I just used HTMLEditorKit, got list of it's actions, and assigned actions to buttons. Then JTextPane.getText() returns the html-formatted string.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use the 'write' method of 'HTMLEditorKit'

- http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/text/html/HTMLEditorKit.html

The document gonna be write in HTML 3.2